# Contacting api via postman

Tags: curl, cookies, postman

I am looking to contact an api via postman. Their documentation has an example using curl and i am able to auth using that. I want to use postman because of the ease of use and because in my opinion it really does make working with Api's easier. Their example is like this

```
 curl https://app.finaleinventory.com/newcentury/api/auth -c /tmp/cookie 
         -d '{"username":"test","password":"test"}'
```

It instructs you to save a cookie with a session secret and then to send subsequent posts using both the secret and the cookie as well. How could i accomplish this using postman? Their developer link is here http://www.finaleinventory.com/developer/example. Thanks

Comment: what type of security/authentication is used on your backend?

Comment: Im not sure what they use on their back end.

Comment: without knowing, the security part of the call is guesswork

Comment: is it a post or get?

Comment: Im doing a post to authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite easy, Obviously change the username and password accordingly

[image]

cookies (according to https://www.getpostman.com/docs/interceptor_cookies):

```
1. Make sure the interceptor is enabled.

2. Include the “Cookie” header in the headers section

eg. Cookie: name=value; name2=value2

3. Send the request. The cookies you set will be sent by Chrome along with your request.
```

Comment: Awesome, tried this and it worked, how do i then send the cookie? and where can i find it? I see it after turning on interceptor but how would i send it with a post?

Comment: assuming the server will accept the session ID in the same call, change the body to `{"username":"test","password":"test", "sessionID": "sessionID"}` or the correct values

Comment: So I see the JsessionId in postman but the documentation says it needs the cookie included in subsequent requests. How is that handled. Thank you for being so helpful btw.

Comment: Its fine, vote as correct so other people can find the answer?

Comment: How would i then send a post. Would the username and password go in the header along with the cookie? I tried that and got a 401.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138236/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-leonardo-trimarchi).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering how you would do a post to an api like this what i found that worked for me was to include the required cookie name and value in the header and for the particular api i was dealing with include it in the body. Also, make sure that you have interceptor on so that Postman will send the cookie as well. It's not very different from what the correct answer is the last piece i needed was to include the cookie name and value in the body of the post

`{"cookiename":"cookieValue", "ProductId":"1"}`

[image]